# How can I make a division in jquery with a selector attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have a select box:

```
<select class="horse">
    <option value="white" value2="1">white</option>
    <option value="black" value2="2">black</option>
</select>
```

And I want to make a division with a number I already calculated:

So if I write my code like this, I get the grandTotal `500`:

```
   $('select').change(function() {
        $(".grandTotal").html($('.somethingelse').val()*100))               
   });
```

With the following code I would like now to get the grandTotal `250` if I select the opton `black`.

```
   $('select').change(function() {
        $(".grandTotal").html(($('.somethingelse').val()*100))/$('.horse').attr('value2'))              
   });
```

But it is not working. Do you know why?

```
  <div class="grandTotal"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the attribute from the selected option

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $(".grandTotal").html(($('.somethingelse').val() * 100) / $('.horse :selected').attr('value2'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="horse">
  <option value="white" value2="1">white</option>
  <option value="black" value2="2">black</option>
</select>

<select class="somethingelse">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>

<div class="grandTotal"></div>
```

Comment: please speak also about parseFloat. It only works because he's lucky, it won't work anymore as soon as he's adding, or doing things like "500"/"2"

Comment: hello, I can not use `this` because it should change also when any other select box on my page is changed